# How to create a "VALID DOCX" using Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, docx, cfml

**Edit**
When we read a valid .docx file using `<cfzip>` we'll get an xml string as a result. We can edit this xml

```
<cfzip action="read" file="#pathToDocx#" entrypath="word\document.xml" variable="xmlString">
<cfset xmlPara = xmlparse(xmlString).document.body>
```

**Question** I am trying trying to create a valid docx file using ColdFusion and trying to get access to document.xml file.We can get access to the "document.xml" file which contains all the data in that docx file when we read. But can we reverse engineer this to save update a .docx file?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you googled? What have you read? What effort have you put into solving this yourself?

Comment: Yes. It is just XML, so it can be manipulated. However, that requires an understanding of [OOXML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) (and of course XML functions) which is way to broad a topic for S.O. If you do a search, there are a number of existing thread and projects on just this topic.